# How should I pass a variable to another class?

Tags: java, android

I have declared a variable  named public static  String parameterForURL which I need to pass `SendRequest` class so that total URL would be together like
URL=http://www.eurekabd.com/shakil/home.php/?+shaki,123.
But Server is receiving  `/shakil/shakil.php/?[Ljava.lang.String;@ce6cdf7`

```
public static  String parameterForURL = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    parameterForURL ="shakil,123";

    doorOpenButtonActionClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new SendRequest().execute();
            resultContainer="";
        }
    });
}

public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String[] paramparameterForURL) {

        Log.v("Passed=",paramparameterForURL.toString());

        try{
            Log.v("Passed=",paramparameterForURL.toString());
            //String serv_url="http://www.eurekabd.com/shakil/home.php"+paramparameterForURL.toString();

            serv_url="http://192.168.0.109/shakil/shakil.php/?"+paramparameterForURL;
            //serv_url += paramparameterForURL;
            Log.e("Server Url",serv_url.toString());
            URL url = new URL(serv_url);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
**How to make can i pass this paramparameterForURL variable so that i can get my desired out put **

Comment: Will every instance of your activity always share the same value of this variable? If not, then it should not be static.

Comment: What class do you need to pass the value to? Is it another activity? Or is it some other class?

Comment: i need to pass the value from onCreate() to public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing `paramparameterForURL.toString()`. Since `paramparameterForURL` is a String **array**, it's `toString` method will not return it's contents but an identifier like `[Ljava.lang.String;@ce6cdf7`. That's the class name, an @ sign and then the hash code of the object. Therefore the server will receive

/shakil/shakil.php/?[Ljava.lang.String;@ce6cdf7

What you want to do is something like the following

```
public static  String parameterForURL = "";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    parameterForURL ="shakil,123";

    doorOpenButtonActionClass.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new SendRequest().execute(parameterForURL);
            resultContainer="";
        }
    });
}

public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String[] paramparameterForURL) {

        Log.v("Passed=",paramparameterForURL[0].toString());

        try{
            Log.v("Passed=",paramparameterForURL[0].toString());
            //String serv_url="http://www.eurekabd.com/shakil/home.php"+paramparameterForURL[0].toString();

            serv_url="http://192.168.0.109/shakil/shakil.php/?"+paramparameterForURL[0];
            //serv_url += paramparameterForURL;
            Log.e("Server Url",serv_url.toString());
            URL url = new URL(serv_url);
```

You pass the `parameterForURL` as an argument to your AsyncTask and then in the async task you get the first item of the array, since you only specified one parameter.

Comment: Note that there is no reason to keep the `parameterForURL` as a static class variable. It can be a local variable inside `onCreate()` instead.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree with that.

Comment: Thank you Sir. As i am new to this language so it was hard for me. But i learned  a lot form u and it. it finally worked for me. thanks a lot. It worked for me.

Comment: No problem :-) if it worked for you, you could accept the answer with that green check mark next to my answer

Comment: No issue :) I know the excitement when you finally fix a problem. Btw you somehow boosted my reputation by 150 or so with that accept xD

Comment: Twometer, it was an association bonus. You must have recently signed up for another stack site :P

Comment: Ah ok yea that's what SO sais in the reputation tab thanks :)

Comment: Yep, that's how I knew ;) You're welcome! [In case you want to know more about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you do not need a `public static` variable at all here. Instead, just pass the value directly to the execute() method of AsyncTask:

```
new SendRequest().execute("shakil,123");
```

If you want to store the parameter in a variable, make it a local variable, not a static class variable:

```
String paramForURL = "shakil,123";
new SendRequest().execute(paramForURL);
```

Now to recieve the variable, you need to get it out of the array parameter:

```
 protected String doInBackground(String[] paramparameterForURL) {

    Log.v("Passed=",paramparameterForURL[0]);
    // ...
}
```

The problem with your original code is that you are converting an array to a String. Instead, you need to get an element of the array by indexing as shown above.

Comment: That's exactly my answer copied

Comment: Oh ok xD Well thats no problem at all I've had that problem too already :p

Comment: @Twometer There are two small differences in my answer: 1. I suggest removing the static class variable. 2. I don't call `toString()` on the array element which is already `String`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a property inside your class and constructor to fill it

try putting this inside your class :

```
private String _myParam;

public SendRequest ( string myParam ){
    _myParam = myParam;
    } 

// then continue with your try catch.
```

then when you create the instance :

```
new SendRequest("My awesome param").execute();
```

i hope this helps :)

Comment: While this works, it requires creating a new object whenever the parameter changes. Instead, AsyncTask is designed to pass parameters to the `execute()` method. This allows reusing the same AsyncTask object with different parameters.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice did they change it? It used to be that you had to create a new instance of the AsyncTask to execute on or you'd get an error.

Comment: @codeMagic It has been a while since I used AsyncTask, so you are probably right about that detail.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice what u use now instead of AsyncTask. if u share iwill be able to learn that.

Comment: @Md.SojibAhmed I have not used AsyncTask recently because I have not done much Android programming at all in the last year.